# How to catch optioned and non optioned arguments correctly?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, input, options, getopts

I want to write a shell script which will take some arguments with some options and print that arguments. Suppose the name of that script is `abc.ksh`. Usage of that script is -
`./abc.ksh -[a <arg>|b <arg>|c|d] <some_string>`
Now I write a shell script which will take options and arguments

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Default Values
vara=","
varb=false
varbname=""
varc=false

# Scanning inputs
while getopts :a:b:cd option
do
        case $option in
                a) vara=$OPTARG;;
                   #shift $((OPTIND-1));;
                b) varb=true
                   varbname=$OPTARG;;
                   #shift $((OPTIND-1));;
                c) varc=true;;
                   #shift $((OPTIND-1));;
                d) echo "Usage $0 \-[a|b|c|d] <filename>"
                   exit 0;;
                \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG. Please run '$0 -h' for help"
                    exit 1;;
                :) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument. Please run '$0 -d' for help"
                   exit 1;;
esac
done

print "Args: $* \nvara: $vara \noptfile: $varb \nvarbname: $varbname \nvarc: $varc"
```

**Examples of Correct Inputs:**

- `./abc.ksh -a "sample text" "some_string"`
- `./abc.ksh "some_string" -a "sample text"`
- `./abc.ksh -asample\ text some_string`
- etc...

`some_string` input is not catch in my script. How can I catch that?

Comment: When you're getting to the level of complication where you're asking yourself this sort of question, I think it's time to shift to asking "should I be using a full scripting language instead"? Python, perl, whatever — they all have pre-existing modules for handing this gracefully and transparently.

Comment: Posix shell is a very capable scripting language, very capable of doing what he is asking in this question. This is not at all a complicated thing.

Comment: Perl's `Getopt::Long` will extract the options and leave the non-option arguments in @ARGV.

Comment: just use `getopt` ? `man getopt` I've only used getopt in C so I can't really say exactly what the code should look like, but it seems like better than implementing getopt yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is typical for programs to force the "some_string" part to be the last argument so that `.abc.ksh "some_string" -a "sample text"` is an error. If you do this, then after parsing the options, `$OPTIND` holds the index to the last argument (the `"some_string"` part).

If that is not acceptable, then you can check at the beginning (before you enter the `while` to see if there is a non-prefixed argument. This will let you have `"some_string"` at the beginning and at the end. If you needed to have it in the middle, you could either not use `getopts` or you could have two sets of `getopts`. When the first one errors out, it could be due to the non-prefixed argument; get it and start a new `getopts` to get the remaining args. Or you can skip getopts all together and roll your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

After capturing your options

```
shift $OPTIND
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  some_str="$1"
else
  echo "Error: missing argument" >&2
fi
```

Comment: For `./abc.ksh "some_string" -a "sample text"`, it will not work.

Comment: Well for getopts, you're constrained by the tool: "Any of the following identifies the end of options: the special option --,  *finding  an argument  that  does  not begin with a -*, or encountering an error."